# Apns c# exception unable to read data from the transport connection an existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: c#, ios, apple-push-notifications, pushsharp

Im trying to send apple push notification with valid p12 and token as following:

```
void connect()
        {
            client = new TcpClient();

            //Notify we are connecting
            var eoc = this.OnConnecting;
            if (eoc != null)
                eoc(this.appleSettings.Host, this.appleSettings.Port);

            try
            {
                client.Connect(this.appleSettings.Host, this.appleSettings.Port);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new ConnectionFailureException("Connection to Host Failed", ex);
            }

            if (appleSettings.SkipSsl)
            {
                networkStream = client.GetStream();
            }
            else
            {
                stream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false,
                    new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback((sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; }),
                    new LocalCertificateSelectionCallback((sender, targetHost, localCerts, remoteCert, acceptableIssuers) =>
                    {
                        return certificate;
                    }));

                try
                {
                    stream.AuthenticateAsClient(this.appleSettings.Host, this.certificates, System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls, false);
                    //stream.AuthenticateAsClient(this.appleSettings.Host);
                }
                catch (System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException ex)
                {
                    throw new ConnectionFailureException("SSL Stream Failed to Authenticate as Client", ex);
                }

                if (!stream.IsMutuallyAuthenticated)
                    throw new ConnectionFailureException("SSL Stream Failed to Authenticate", null);

                if (!stream.CanWrite)
                    throw new ConnectionFailureException("SSL Stream is not Writable", null);

                networkStream = stream;
            }

            //Start reading from the stream asynchronously
            Reader();
        }

    }
```

when i changed the line code: System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls to System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Ssl3 i get "Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream"

How can i send APNS?
How can i send apns???

Answer (score 1):

SSL3 has been dumped by Apple (amongst others) within the last month (Oct 2014) due to a major security flaw; known as POODLE(Padding Oracle On Downgraded Legacy Encryption).